# Why is the condition $xyz = x+y+z+2$ equivalent to $\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1+z} = 1?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is the condition $$xyz = x+y+z+2$$ equivalent to $$\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1+z} = 1?$$

I tried to to start by dividing by $xyz$ to get $$1 = \frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{xz} + \frac{1}{xy} + \frac{2}{xyz}$$ but the rhs does not seem to result in $\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1+z}$ by any means.

We have also that $$\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(1+z\right)=1+z+y+x+yz+xz+xy+xyz$$

so I can equate $$x+y+z+2 = (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)-1-x-y-z-xy-xz-yz$$ which gives $$2x+2y+2z+3=(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)-xy-xz-yz$$ but it aint easy to get this either to the correct form. Is there some another manipulations I can do?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)$, assuming   $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ne0$

Answer (score 3):

The two conditions are only equivalent, if $x,y,z \neq -1$ (else the second condition wouldn't make any sense).

You can start with
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+y} + \frac{1}{1+z} = 1
$$
Multiplying by $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)$ gives
$$
(1+y)(1+z) + (1+x)(1+z) + (1+x)(1+y) = (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)
$$
Multiplying this out gives
$$
1+y+z+yz +1 +x+z+zx + 1 +x+y+xy = 1 +x+y+z+xy+yz+zx +xyz
$$
and hence $x+y+z+2 = xyz$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a polynomial $P(t)$ with roots $x,y$ and $z$. Note that, given the initial condition $xyz = x+y+z+2$, the polynomial must be $P(t) = t^3+ax^2+bx+a-2$ by Vieta's formulas.

We now know that $P(t-1)$ has roots $x+1,y+1$ and $z+1$ and $$\begin{split} P(t-1) &= (t-1)^3 + a(t-1)^2+b(t-1) + a -2 \\&= t^3 + (a-3)t^2 + (b-2a+3)t-b+2a-3 \end{split}$$ so we now conclude $$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1) =  b-2a+3 = (x+1)(y+1)+(x+1)(z+1)+(y+1)(z+1)$$

Comment: Doesn't this show only one direction?

Comment: I believe this is enough for both directions, just start with a polynomial $$P(t-1) = t^3 + (a-3)t^2 + (b-2a+3)t-b+2a-3$$ for any $a,b$ and with roots $x+1,y+1,z+1$. Now follow what I did in the other direction.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.